# Why is msgmerge not updating changed strings?

Tags: python, localization, translation, gettext

Our *.po file has the following:

```
#: store/jinja2/store/macros.html:35
#, python-format
msgid "%(percent)s%% Trained Crew"
msgstr "%%(percent)s% Eğitimli Mürettebat"
```

Obviously this is wrong. The translator did not understand escaping, and moved too few percent signs. We got a corrected *.pot back with this:

```
#: store/jinja2/store/macros.html:35
#, python-format
msgid "%(percent)s%% Trained Crew"
msgstr "%%%(percent)s Eğitimli Mürettebat"
```

We attempted to use msgmerge to up date our *.po from the *.pot like this:

```
msgmerge django.po django.pot --no-fuzzy-matching --no-wrap --update
```

However, this does not result in the *.po entry changing. It is still the first value. Do I need to add an additional flag to force it to update old strings? Or do I need to delete and regenerate the *.po file each time I have an update?

Comment: What you describe sounds confusing.  What do you mean with "we got a corrected *.pot back".  The pot file is normally a newly generated po template, with no translations at all.  The `msgmerge` then takes any translations from the old po file, and generates a new po file with the msgid:s from the pot files, and any matching translations from the old po file.

Comment: This is inherently confusing, because po and pot are the exact same format, and differ only by convention. My understanding is that I generate a po, copy it and rename it to pot and send it to the translators. It then remains a pot after it's translated until I merge it back into the po. It our actual process we never actually rename it and its called po the whole time. Maybe I have the arguments backward? I will check when I get back on Monday.

Comment: My intention wasn't to complain about your use of the terms, more to say that I didn't understand what you were saying.  I don't understand what the content of _django.po_ and _django.pot_ is in your example.

Comment: The exact problem was that I had the arguments reversed, because I was confused about the terms. (The second problem is that msgmerge does not work the way I want it to anyway. )